# How do you maintain continuity in race definitions across time?

Tags: collegescorecard

If you're looking to track enrollment of minority students over time, what's the best way to accommodate changes in IPEDS definitions after 2009?

I am presuming `UGDS_WHITE` (after 2009) maps to `UGDS_WHITENH` and `UGDS_BLACK` maps to `UGDS_BLACKNH`.

Looks like things get a bit tougher converting `UGDS_ASIAN` and `UGDS_NHPI` back to `UGDS_API`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that IPEDS detailed descriptions of changes in race categories are noted here: https://nces.ed.gov/ipeds/news_room/ana_Changes_to_10_25_2007_169.asp . In developing trend reports, NCES converts race categories to the new naming categories and shows the old Asian and Pacific Islander Category and the new Asian and the new Hawaiian and other Pacific Islander categories with N/A in the appropriate cells where old and new reporting begins and ends.  A resource that can provide assistance on this matter is the IPEDS Data Use Help  Desk (866) 558-0658 or ipedstools@rti.org